# problem with change radio buttons in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to build some set of quizes with a question and multiple choice of answers (radio buttons). But the managed state doesn't work:

1. First question should be with blank answers
2. Click the answer's `input` - marks the input as checked and increment the `questionIndex` by 1
3. Second question is rendered **but** the marked input from the prev question stays marked with prev answer

I want to change them with the managed state, but unsuccessfully

```
function Quiz () {
  var questions = [{text: 'question_text1', answers: [{isTrue: true}, {isTrue: false}, {isTrue: false}, {isTrue: false}]}, {text: 'question_text2', answers: [{isTrue: false}, {isTrue: false}, {isTrue: false}, {isTrue: true}]}]
  var questionIndex = 0;
  var updateQuizAnswer = () => { questionIndex++}
  return <Question data={questions[questionIndex]} updateQuizAnswer={updateQuizAnswer} /> }
}
function Question (props) {
  return <div>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
    <AnswersList answers_data={props.answers} updateQuizAnswer={updateQuizAnswer} />
  </div>
}
function AnswersList(props: AnswersProps) {
  return { props.answers_data.map(ans => <Answer key={ans} answerText={ans.answerText} updateQuizAnswer={this.props.updateQuizAnswer} /> )}
}

class Answer extends Component<AnswersProps, AnswersState> {
  state = { isClicked: false }
  check = e => { this.setState({isClicked: true}); this.props.updateQuizAnswer(); };

  render() {
    return <label>
      <input type="radio"
        checked={this.state.isClicked}
        onChange={this.check}
      />
      <span>{this.props.answerText}</span>
    </label>
  }
}
```

Here is the full code 
https://github.com/ShadeeCat/dental-tests

Comment: This code would be better implemented as a checkbox. "Checkboxes are similar to radio buttons, but with an important distinction: radio buttons are designed for selecting one value out of a set, whereas checkboxes let you turn individual values on and off." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: I need only one option of the true answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class Answer extends Component { 
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    state = {
        value: this.props.answerText,
        isTrue: false,
        isChecked: false,
        question_01:"",
        question_02:"",
    }
    this.check=this.check.bind(this) 
   }


    // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Readonly<AnswersProps>, nextState: Readonly<AnswersState>, nextContext: any): boolean {
    //     return this.state.value !== nextProps.value;
    // }
    // componentDidUpdate(prevProps: Readonly<AnswersProps>, prevState: Readonly<AnswersState>, snapshot?: any): void {
    //     console.log(this.state.isChecked)
    // }
     check(e,question){
        var data=this.state;
        data[question]=e.target.value
        this.setState({data})
    }

    render () {
        return 
        <label>
            {/* First question */}
            <input type="radio" name={this.props.name1} checked={this.state.question_1==="value11"} onClick={(e)=>this.check(e,'question_1') } value="value11"/>{ this.props.answerText }
            <input type="radio" name={this.props.name1} checked={this.state.question_1==="value12"} onClick={(e)=>this.check(e,'question_1') } value="value12"/>{ this.props.answerText }
            {/* Second question */}
            <input type="radio" name={this.props.name2} checked={this.state.question_2==="value21"} onClick={(e)=>this.check(e,'question_2') } value="value21"/>{ this.props.answerText }
            <input type="radio" name={this.props.name2} checked={this.state.question_2==="value22"} onClick={(e)=>this.check(e,'question_2') } value="value22"/>{ this.props.answerText }
        </label>
    } 
}
```

Comment: it's doesn't helped. =(
Now I can't choose the other options and the value still in last answer every time in all queezes..

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your solution.

Comment: Hello @N'Bayramberdiyev, let me update my answer for making it more general

Answer (score 0):

May be You are looking something like this.

Please Try This [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-dent-x53ow)

A Radio Box only be checked if

```
<input
      type="radio"
      checked={this.props.isTrue}
      name={this.props.name}
      value={this.props.answerText}
      onChange={this.check}
    />
```

Since your answer has already `isTrue` property you can checked it with your provided Props

Comment: The pleasure is mine!!

Comment: I need to het user's answers - so I need it unchecked and afterwards to get the clicked input. If I set `checked={this.state.isChecked}` created before and set to false, this input remains checked on the second question as well. I need to manage the state in some way that will be applied only the specific input

Comment: Please check updated answer..  I thought you have to show checked for correct answer. Now by default each question will be not checked.